# Clearing caches directory displays SQLite bug

Tags: swift

I am downloading temporary files into the `.cachesDirectory` in my Swift app. Occasionally, I'll have to clear the folder if a download is interrupted. To do that, I use the following:

[What are the best practice for clearing cache directory in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004124/what-are-the-best-practice-for-clearing-cache-directory-in-ios/41989137#41989137)

This *works*, but logs this annoying error when attempting to clear:

```
[logging] BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by API violation: vnode unlinked while in use: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/845AA3CF-4CFE-2DF3-91A5-D87211D32DC0/Library/Caches/com.myapp/Cache.db
```

Any ideas on how to make this message disappear?

Comment: It looks to me like you are clearing a cached file that belongs to Sqlite. I didn't look to closely at the linked question but you should take care to only clear downloaded files and nothing else.

Comment: That makes sense, let me try that. Thanks!